# Trigger to keep a count of rows

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a Product table which stores list of products. For some purpose I need to keep count of total number of active products available in products table. For simplicity, lets say there are 03 columns in Product table - id, prod_name, prod_datetill. All the products with NULL value in prod_datetill are considered as active. Instead of querying the product table everytime, I thought of creating a trigger in Product table which will increase the count in Prodcount table. Following function I created for the trigger :-

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.product_count_increment()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    
            
    UPDATE prodcount SET prod_count = prod_count + 1;
    
    RETURN NEW;

END

$BODY$;
```

However, I think this will not be inconsistent since on updating the prod_datetill column, the count should reduce also. Is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write trigger function like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.product_count_update()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE prodcount SET prod_count = (select count(*)::integer from prodcount where prod_datetill is null);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

the trigger should be `after update` .

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to NOT try maintaining a running total. Doing so you need to worry about not only Inserts, but also Deletes and Update of prod_datetill column.  Better and simpler to just create a view that derives your count when accessed. That way all the processing for any DML is automatically handled without any additional code. Further since this is a simple view it is update-able.

```
create view active_product_counts
       ( id
       , prod_name
       , prod_datetill
       , prod_active_count
       ) as
 select id
      , prod_name
      , prod_datetill
      , count(*) filter (where prod_datetill is null) over( partition by prod_name)
   from products;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e30c88071cdf7c3683eeaf772e607f71). I would hope id, or some other column, is unique but you didn't indicate therefore the example allows duplicates.

Comment: Yes, ID is a unique column. The idea behind creating the trigger was to avoid the additional cost of querying the products table when number of rows will be huge. Am I wrong in thinking this way?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Actually i do do believe it is wrong way of thinking. It appears you are optimizing the system for a minor query. As it lays out you have a single row single column trigger. But this column will be updated for virtually every DML on a very active table. This means LOCKS and waits. The other item what is your definition of huge?  It seems developers new to databases always overestimate the relative size. IMHO a table with 500M rows is defiantly large, but far smaller that huge.